# Java shorter encryption

Tags: java, string, encryption, classpath, obfuscation

I'm trying to encrypt a long string in java, anywhere from 200 - 500 characters long, into an encrypted / obfuscated (Either one will work for me) string that i can later decrypt back into the original 200 - 500 character string. The catch is that I need the encrypted string to be no longer than 32 characters (I want the encrypted string to fit nicely on a console line). Can anyone help me out with a method of doing this..? If there even is one? I was searching for a while and could only find things like base64 or AES which output string that are way too long..

Comment: This will depend on what that 200-500 char string contains since you also need _compression_. If those chars can't be compressed then you can't represent 4000 bits of information using 256 bits :-)

Comment: What is the character space of the original string?  Just alphanumeric?  Is the input case sensitive?

Comment: Mathematically, this is impossible. What you _can_ do is compress it using Huffman coding and then encrypting it, but that would mean storing the dictionary used for the coding into the encrypted output -- in short, you don't gain any place. At least, nothing to write home about, and very probably not into 32 bytes.

Comment: The input is case case sensitive, only alpha numeric characters (Mainly configuration settings like an sql server domain name and port). I did think that the differences in bits would be a huge issue, but i thought i'd ask anyway..

Comment: Do you want to encryption or encoding? These are very different concepts.

Comment: That's why i said "encrypted / obfuscated" :3

Comment: "either one" isn't an acceptable answer. The goals are fundamentally different: encryption attempts to hide information, enconding doesn't (not really).

Comment: Either one = Whichever would better achieve what i'm requesting..

Comment: @thefiscster510 I believe all modern encryption algorithms will output something larger than its input due to padding. Compression is not a goal in encryption.

Comment: I have such an algorithm, and I'll even give it away for free but you have to buy my perpetual motion machine. Delivery is by Unicorn.

Comment: @GregS.. I love you... lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 256^200 possible strings of length 200 (assuming you are using 8 bit extended ASCII characters 0-255). There are 256^32 possible strings of size 32.

This means that any function that converted any 200 character string to a 32 character one, will inevitably end up converting more than one input string to the same output string - because there are simply too few output strings possible (see [Pigeonhole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)).

You could easily come up with a hashing function that maps an input string to a 32 character output, but since more than one string might map to the same output, it would be impossible to reverse the process to get the input string given the output.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way for lossless-compression for every possible 200 character string in a 32 character one. 
That is simply impossible.

Example to understand this:
Assume there we have only ASCII:

200 characters that means 127^200 possible 200 character words

There are only 127^32 possible words of length 32.
Therefore it cannot exist a method to translate each 200 character word to an other 32 character word, which would be necessary if you want to be able to convert it bag to the 200 character word (without errors)

Math says that it is impossible what you request for.

Comment: Well... if you know that the character set for the 200-500 characters is severely restricted and you know that the 32 characters have a lot of bits in them, then it might still be possible.

Comment: @templatetypedef: The question does give no clue that we can suggest that.

Comment: Oh, I completely agree.  I was just mentioning it for completeness.